# How to prevent an android activity to get killed

Tags: android, background, kill

I have developed an application that does require to do constant network activity. This  Activity does the network connections thru an AsyncTask, sometime this work being done in background (application not having focus). My application sometimes gets killed after 30 mins, even if the system does not seem to lack resources (memory).

I have read the Activity life cycle in the  [Application Fundamentals section on developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html), but can't find an answer. What would be the proper way to programmatically prevent my Activty to get killed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) and make sure it stays active (by first starting it and simply not stopping it) the application wont be killed (unless it's extremely low on memory of course).

Answer (score 3):

You should use a [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) instead of using an Activity to do work in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Does your application have to be an activity? Can it utilize a background service?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle

Comment: Thanks Mitch, I considered the service option, but my application has a lot of GUI. I understand that I should convert the part of my application that needs to run in the background as a service, there are not other possibility ? Thank you.