# Android: Autorestart application when OS kills it

Tags: android

friends.

I have to do next thing: We are writing special application for our customers. As we know, OS kills application sometimes (f.e low memory). So question is: Can i handle moment when OS killing it. I've read about onDestroy() event, but some people says, that event doesnt fired. Is it true?

Common question, can i handle OS killing application some way and restart it again.

I know, that is not good idea, but customers asks us about functionality like this.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685269/how-to-prevent-an-android-activity-to-get-killed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712245/android-broadcastreceiver-to-restart-killed-crashed-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it alarm driven using the **AlarmManager** class, check if your activity/app is up every few seconds (or minutes) and re-launch the activity if its been killed.

> So the max time it can be down is the interval between two 'ticks' of
>   the alarm

Comment: I need two points of reputation for voting :)

Thank you! Maybe you can give some example of AlarmManager and re-launch?